# How to efficiently recalculate the values of large amounts of data?

Tags: mongodb

I have several collections in MongoDB:

payment

```json
{
  "_id":{
    "$oid":"6060ded06aa032495d640536"
  },
  "type":"",
  "amount":10,
  "createdAt":{
    "date":{
      "$date":"2021-03-03T16:01:14.137Z"
    },
    "timestamp":1614787274.137138
  },
  "finishedAt":{
    "date":{
      "$date":"2021-03-03T16:13:15.678Z"
    },
    "timestamp":1614787995.678263
  },
  "status":true,
  "state":"finished",
  "destination":{
    "identificator":"1234"
  }
}
```

account

```json
{
  "_id":{
    "$oid":"60677a2c88b356160e415a1e"
  },
  "name":"",
  "providerAccount":{
    "identificator":"1234"
  },
  "targetAmount":0,
  "currentAmount":0,
  "status":false,
  "state":false,
  "priority":false,
  "createdAt":{
    "date":{
      "$date":"2021-03-29T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "timestamp":1616976000
  }
}
```

I need to check each `payment` if it matches the `account` in the system. If `destination.identificator == providerAccount.identificator` I need to change the `payment` `type` to "internal" and add the payment `amount` to the `currentAmount` in the `account`.

At the moment, I have a python script that does all this by iterating over each payment, but the problem is that there are more than a million such payments, and such a process can take a very long time.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write two different Aggregation queries which will perform their own lookup operations on the alternating collections and update the values based on logics and conditions.

> Note: The execution order is very important for this to work

> Note: For both the Aggregation queries, I will be making use of the `$merge` stage which will work only on MongoDB version >= 4.4
> If you are using any earlier versions of MongoDB, loop through the records of the Aggregation results and update the documents manually using `PyMongo` instead of the `$merge` pipeline stage which will be the last stage of the Pipelines.

The first query has to be performed on `payment` collection, which will check if the link exists in the `account` collection or not.

```
db.payment.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "account",
      "let": {
        "invIdentifactor": "$destination.identificator"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$providerAccount.identificator",
                "$$invIdentifactor"
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      "as": "matchedAcc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "matchedAcc": {
        "$ne": []
      }
    },
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "type": {
        "$literal": "internal"
      }
    },
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "payment",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge",
      "whenNotMatched": "discard"
    },
  },
])
```

[MongoDB Playground sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AONPPcTx8mT)

Next the Aggregation query for account collection based on `"type": "internal"` condition added by the previous query.

> Note: If there are already documents with `"type": "internal"` value in payment collection, change `type` to a different unique key name in the `$project` stage and update it in the below query and finally unset the key after all the process is done.

```
db.account.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "payment",
      "let": {
        "accIdentifactor": "$providerAccount.identificator"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$destination.identificator",
                "$$accIdentifactor"
              ],
            },
            "type": "internal",
          },
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$providerAccount.identificator",
            "totalAmount": {
              "$sum": "$amount"
            }
          },
        },
      ],
      "as": "matchedPayment"
    },
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gt": [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$matchedPayment.totalAmount",
              0
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      },
    },
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "currentAmount": {
        "$add": [
          "$currentAmount",
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$matchedPayment.totalAmount",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "account",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge",
      "whenNotMatched": "discard"
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PXre8Hx3qon)

Additionally, you can pass the `allowDiskUse: true` option on Aggregation commands and also consider perform indexing on `providerAccount.identificator` and `destination.identificator` keys to speed this up if required and later delete those indexes.

Let me know if you want an explanation of all the stages and operators in the aggregation pipeline.